# How to setup a Middle-ware file in nextJs project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware, next.js13

I am currently working on a project using Next.js. Overall, things are progressing smoothly, but I've encountered an issue with my middleware.ts file. Despite diligently following the [Middleware docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware) ,   the middleware doesn't seem to be triggering as expected. Below is the content of my `middleware.ts` file:

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
 
// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
      console.log("it ran")
      
    return NextResponse.json({"hello":"middleware"})

 
}
```

Strangely, neither the response nor the console.log statement is being executed. To provide more context, here is the structure of my project:

[image]

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this issue.

Comment: Did you look in the vscode terminal for the log? it should print "I ran"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `middleware != api`

Your middleware file *should not* return **JSON** or anything other than `NextResponse.next()`. You have to return `NextResponse.next()` for your app to go where it should go. If you do not return `NextResponse.next()`, then your request is stuck in the middleware.

Modifying your code to this will make it work.

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log("it ran");
  
  // here, you can do other works like, check if the user is logged in
  // or if the user's ip is in the blocked list etc.

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```